# What are the correct form of the following 2 expressions

Tags: grammaticality, expression-choice

I am working on a simple application which predicts your wake up time if you go to bed at the moment. For example: if you go to bed at **12am** and set your alarm, you should set your alarm to **8am**. Is it correct if I write

> Wake up time for getting up lively: 7.30 - 8.30?

Also I want to predict the bedtime if you set your alarm to **8am** the app says to you that you should go to bed at **12am**. Is it correct if I write

> Bedtime for getting up lively at 8am: 12:00 - 12:30?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

target wake-up time to get up lively
and
target bedtime to ensure you get up lively

Comment: thanks :), it sounds better, but I am not sure.

Comment: just wait a while and few nore suggestions would pop up from people. by the way are you insistent on using the words get-up and wake-up or something else would do?